# How to fix an ExternalError in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am just starting out programming, I know my code looks terrible but I need to get this fixed.

```
list1 = {"Ian", "Gavin", "Wriley", "Jack", "Blake"}

choices = (str(input("0 = Quit \n1 = Look at person\'s info \n2 = Add 
a person \n3 = Edit persons\'s info \n4 = Delete a person \n5 = View 
list of people \nWhat would you like to do: ")))

for everythng in choices:
    print(choices)
if choices == "0":
    quit()
elif choices == "1":
    print(list)
elif choices == "2":
    add_person = input("What is the name you want to add: ")
    list.append(0, add_person)
    choices
elif choices == "3":
    edit = input("Name of person to edit:")
    list1.append(edit.capitalize())
elif choices == "4":
    delete_user = input("Persons name to remove: ")
    list.remove(delete_user)
elif choices == "5":
    print (list1)
else:
    print("You did something wrong.")
```

The error says this:

> AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'append' on line 16 in main.py

Line 16 is `list1.append(edit.capitalize())`

Basically I need to user to say 3 to edit the dictionary. How do I do this?

Comment: I don't know if your actual code looks like this but you have `list1.append()` and also `list.append()`. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 1):

Your "list" is not a list, it is a `set`. Sets don't have an `append` method, hence the error `AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'append'`.

Instead, sets have an `add` method.

In your question you also refer to a dictionary but your code has no dictionaries at all.

Answer (score 1):

`list1` is actually a set. You can change it to a list by changing `list1 = {...}` to `list1 = [...]`. You can also keep it as a set and use `list1.add(...)` instead of `append`. 
EDIT: If you are trying to use a `dict`, then you have to add values like: `list1 = {'name': 'info', 'name 2': info 2, ...}`. To add to this, you would just do `list1['name to change'] = 'new info'`.